Is there a way to access the Transform Pivot Point position using the Blender Python API?
I am currently working on an project that operates in Edit Mode.  The problem I currently have is that I need to access the position of the "Transform Pivot Point" (the reference point that Blender uses when doing Edit Mode operations, i.e. Active Element, Individual Origins, 3D Cursor, Median Point, Bounding Box Center).
The Blender Docs say you can get the current "mode" of the Transform Pivot Point (https://docs.blender.org/api/3.3/bpy_types_enum_items/transform_pivot_items_full.html), but there seems to be nothing on the actual data of the Transform Pivot Point itself.
Are there any built in methods or means to obtain the position of the Transform Pivot Point?

Access the Value
import bpy

print(
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point
)

Calculate the position
You need to calculate it yourself based on your situation
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

ob = bpy.context.object
mat = ob.matrix_world

enum_value = bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point
if enum_value == "BOUNDING_BOX_CENTER":
    print(
        mat @ (sum([Vector(v) for v in ob.bound_box], Vector()) / 8.0)
    )

Tips



Perhaps a dirty hack, but you could create a vertex and scale it down to 0 to discover the position of the pivot point.
